# Translating a 3D point from one frame to another

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-equations, coordinate-systems, 3d, rotations

Me and my friend have ran into trubbels with translating a point in a 3D-space from one cartesian coordinate system to another.

In this case we have 3 coordinate systems called the *Base-frame*, *h-frame* and *b-frame* (see picture below). From the *Base-frame* we rotate with $\pi$ around the *Base-frame* x-axis in order to reach the *h-frame*. This is done with the following transformation matrix:

$ T_{base}^h  =  \begin{bmatrix} 1,\ \ 0,\ \ 0,\ \ 0\\0,-1,\ \  0,\ \ 
 0\\0,\ \ 0,-1,\ \ 0\\0,\ \ 0,\ \ 0,\ \ 1
\end{bmatrix}$

When this has been done we rotate from the *h-frame* to the *b-frame* by rotating around the *h-frame* x-axis with $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with the following matrix:

$ T_{h}^b  =  \begin{bmatrix} 1,\ \ 0,\ \ 0,\ \ 0 \\ 
0,\ \ 0,-1,\ \ 0\\ 
0,\ \ 1,\ \ 0,\ \ 0\\0,\ \ 0,\ \ 0,\ \ 1
\end{bmatrix}$

We then want to express a coordinate, expressed in the *Base-frame*, say $coord_{base} = [1;1;0;1]$, in the *b-frame* (last 1 just for size). With the knowledge of the frames orientation the point [1;1;0;1] expressed in the *Base-frame*, should become [1;0;1;1] in the *b-frame*. To get this point with the help of our matrices, we perform the following calculation

$coord_{b} = T_{base}^h \ \ T_{h}^b  \ \ coord_{base}$

this, however, yields the point [1;0;-1], and not [1;0;1] as expected. Why? Are we multiplying in the wrong order? Creating the rotation matrices in the wrong order? Are we missing something obvious here?

[Picture of frames and their rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMy1X.jpg)

Grateful for all help we can get!

Comment: The matrices are being multiplied in the wrong order.

Comment: If you compare the last set of coordinate axes with the first set, it's clear that the end result of these two rotations is the same as if you just did a rotation by $\phi=-\frac\pi2$ around the $x$ axis and did no other rotation afterward. Of course that observation will not help much with any example where the rotations are not all around one axis; then you would still need to pay attention to the order of multiplying the matrices.

Comment: You are correct, but in our case the angle between *h-frame* and *b-frame* will vary (in the end), so we can not take this route.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on greg’s comment, yes, you’ve got the matrices in the wrong order. Think about it this way: After transforming $\mathbf x_{base}$ into the $h$-frame, you have $T_{base}^h\mathbf x_{base}$. You then transform this into the $b$-frame, you multiply this by the next transformation matrix, getting $T_h^b(T_{base}^h\mathbf x_{base})$.

More generally, if you’re representing points as *column* vectors, then you left-multiply by the transformation matrix and the transformation cascade grows leftward; if you’re using *row* vectors, you right-multiply by the matrix and the cascade grows rightward.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies!

However, even when if we change the order of the multiplication from $T_{base}^{h} \ T_{h}^b \  coord_{base}$ to $T_{h}^{b} \  T_{base}^{h}  \ coord_{base}$, we still get the same (wrong) answer, which is $coord_b = [1;0;-1]$. This made us believe that the frames somehow got rotated wrongly along the way, and that the *b-frame* especially had been flip $\pi$ around the x-axis. That would explain the coordinate we get. After redoing the calculations in *Matlab*, as seen below, we did however find out that this was NOT the case. The *b-frame* is oriented the same way as in the picture provided earlier. How come the point doesn't "understand" this?

> %Creation of transformation matrices
>
> T_base_h = [1,  0,  0,  0 ; 0, -1,  0,  0 ; 0,  0, -1,  0 ; 0,  0,  0,  1];
>
> T_h_b =     [1,  0,  0,  0; 0,  0, -1,  0; 0,  1,  0,  0; 0,  0,  0,  1];
>
> % Base frame
>
> coord_base = [1;1;0;1]
>
> frame_base = [1,0,0; 0,1,0; 0,0,1];
>
> % h-frame
>
> coord_h = T_base_h * coord_base;
>
> frame_h = frame_base * T_base_h(1:3,1:3)
>
> % b-frame
>
> coord_b = T_h_b * coord_h;
>
> frame_b = frame_h * T_h_b(1:3,1:3)